# Bulk Insert Error Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

[image]
Getting this Error for Bulk Isert. Only for large number of records.

```
switch (actionType)
            {
                case AuditLogSaveAction.Asynchronous:
                    ORMAsyncActionQueue.AuditLog.AddLogsToQueue(logsToSave);
                    break;
                case AuditLogSaveAction.Synchronous:
                    **this.BulkInsert<AuditLog>(logsToSave); <- Exception Thrown here.**
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: IS it possible to show the relevant code instead for this image

Comment: edited the question

Comment: How did you map AuditLog for bulkinsert operation?

Comment: When you say only for large number of records, does it mean that this same case (AuditLogSaveAction.Synchronous) works fine when number of items in logsToSave is small?

Comment: yes when I test with 3 records it is working fine but when I do for 50 records it is failing.

Answer (score 1):

I had same [error](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/workitem/1623). If you use BulkInset with some **concurrent** logic, for example: several threads or tasks, you can take exactly this error. It caused not thread safe code (was fixed at native repository), but corresponding Nuget Package still has this error, so you can easily solve problem - just download repository and replace current Nuget Package with it. [This peace of code contains exception](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#dev/Src/EntityFramework.BulkInsert/ProviderFactory.cs):

```
public static IEfBulkInsertProvider Get(DbContext context)
{
    var connectionTypeName = context.Database.Connection.GetType().FullName;
    if (!Providers.ContainsKey(connectionTypeName))
    {
        throw new BulkInsertProviderNotFoundException(connectionTypeName);
    }

    return Providers[connectionTypeName]().SetContext(context);
}
```

Not thread safe code of `Providers` property, shown above:

```
private static Dictionary<string, Func<IEfBulkInsertProvider>> Providers
{
    get
    {
        //commented pice of code does not exist at Nuget Package
        //lock (ProviderInitializerLockObject)
        //{
            if (_providers == null)
            {
                _providers = new Dictionary<string, Func<IEfBulkInsertProvider>>();

                // bundled providers
                Register<EfSqlBulkInsertProviderWithMappedDataReader>("System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection");
                //Register<EfSqlCeBulkiInsertProvider>("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");
            }
        //}

        return _providers;
    }
}
```